# pip install a package from a private repo but dependencies from PyPi behind a proxy

Tags: python, pip

I would like to install a package hosted on a private repo so I'm doing:

```
pip install myApp -i https://repo.my-organization.net/pypi/myfeed/simple
```

It is working well until some requirements are needed. So there is an attempt to get them from PyPi but there is then an error because PyPi should be reached through a Proxy.
Then, I'm doing:

```
export http_proxy='http://myproxy:0000'
```

and same for https, but then, this is the private repo that is no more reachable... :-(

Is there a way to specify/configure pip in a way it is using the proxy for PyPi repo but not for the private one?

tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `no_proxy` environment variable (comma-separated list of host names which shouldn't go through any proxy) to omit internal hosts such as *my-organization*.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm not familiar with environment variables and what is possible. It works as expected!

Comment: Could either of you indicate what this means for the command?